# Как собрать 64 - битную динамическую библиотеку в VS2015

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

Пытаюсь собрать в 64 -битном формате динамическую библиотеку (.dll).
Сама библиотека прекрасно собираться (.NET Framework 4.5.2), с настройками (Release) (Win32).

Но так как работаю первый раз с VS то не совсем понимаю как "собирать" библиотеки в 64- битном формате.

Как я понял 32-битная библиотека собирается по принципу (как раз в 32 битном формате её собрал)

> далее->далее->далее

Стал искать в книгах(MS.Microsoft.Visual.Basic.2013.Step.by.Step, С/С++ MS Visual C++ 2012 ) и в интернете увы не нашёл, либо просто не справился ((

Думал что в настройках можно поменять платформу в "менеджере конфигураций" но увы win32 это единственное что предлагает менеджер конфигураций.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

при сборке в 64-ричной системе.

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_msg_zero referenced in function nmt_master_command         проект этот   nmt_master.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_msg_zero                           проект этот     obj_sync.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_msg_zero                           проект этот     pdo_proc.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_msg_zero                           проект этот     sdo_proc.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiOpen referenced in function init_controller              проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiInit referenced in function start_master                 проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiClose referenced in function init_controller             проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiStop referenced in function init_controller              проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiStart referenced in function set_controller_bitrate      проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiSetCB referenced in function init_controller         проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiSetBaud referenced in function set_controller_bitrate        проект этот     backinit.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiSetWriteTout referenced in function init_controller          проект этот     inout.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiWrite referenced in function push_all_data           проект этот     inout.obj
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CiRead referenced in function read_handler                     проект этот     shai.lib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не можете собрать 64-битную DLL с настройками проекта `Release Win32`, для этого DLL должна быть скомпилирована как 64-битовая. Для это в окне `Configuration Manager` (показано на вашем скриншоте) щелкните на выпадающий список `Platform` **в строке вашего проекта** и выберите `New...`. В списке `New Platform` выберите `x64`, копируйте из `Win32`. Выберите `x64` в качестве активной конфигурации, затем `Build`.

Comment: сделал как вы описали , но увы выпрыгнуло множество ошибок ;_;

Comment: @timob256, какие конкретно ошибки?

Comment: добавил(обновил)  вопрос, там выложил как раз "вывод" ошибки.

Comment: @timob256,  что это у вас за `CiOpen`, `CiSetBaud`, `msg_zero` и прочие? Это вы какую-то библиотеку используете? Ее надо тоже под 64 бита перекомпилировать, 32-битовые библиотеки не получится подключить к 64-битовой программе.