# Visual Studio 2017 C++ компиляция win32 под 64бит

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

С проблемой не раз сталкивался,но решения не находил.
Выходит такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробывал вручную решения очищать билды,не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
Искал решение моей ошибки почти два дня. Побаловался с настройками и все заработало.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как собрать 64 - битную динамическую библиотеку в VS2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915348/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-64-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-vs2015)

Comment: Если апдейт - это решение, то его надо писать в ответе, а не в вопросе.

Comment: Вы вместо того, чтобы нормально решить проблему, попортили стандартную конфигурацию `Win32`. А когда надо будет 32-битовую программу построить, так и будете одну конфигурацию туда-сюда править?

Comment: Проект не собирался,если указывать Win32 - выбивало ошибку(на скрине). Я уже сколько времени искал решение этой проблемы,а оказалось почти под носом) Да и нормально функционирует программа.